# np.searchsorted negative values

Tags: python, numpy

Why np.searchsorted returns negative indices. My array is around 2million entries or dates. The dates are in sorted order.

I am adding 15mins offset to the existing date...and then trying to locate the nearest date.

So code looks something like this

```
cl1indices = np.searchsorted(pd.to_datetime(currentdata['date']),(pd.to_datetime(currentdata['date'])+timedelta(minutes=duration)),side='right')-1
```

these cl1indices should always be positive, and I see no reason why they can be negative if data is perfectly sorted. Is it some bug in np.searchsorted??

After getting these indices I basically do something like this

```
currentdata['spot'][cl1indices]-currentdata['spot']
```

I filter out those times which are greater than 15+/-alpha seconds apart.

Comment: Can you create a self-contained example that we can run to reproduce the result?

Comment: there was a mistake in my code....apologies for posting an incorrect question :(

Answer (score 0):

Wrong question, can be deleted. This doesn't happen with np.searchsorted